# How to create an auto popup outside an iframe

Tags: html

I have a chat button my website that should create an auto invitation that scrolls across the screen after a visitor is on there for 60 seconds. My problem is that the auto invitation is being embedded in the chat iframe and is not shown across the screen. The website company can't add my code to the back end so I'm stuck with the iframe. How can I change the code so that the auto invitation scrolls across the screen and not in the iframe?

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at [window.top](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/prop_win_top.asp) for the top most, or [window.parent](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/prop_win_parent.asp) for the parent of the current iframe.

These allow you to interact with those "windows" outside of the current iframe "window".

Comment: Probably not, but he's not really said that the hosts are different, just that he's not allowed to change server-side code base for the main site - guess we need more info to be clear on it.

Comment: I don't understand the response, I'm not familiar with codes, but to better understand my issue, please visit my site firm1040.com look at the chat button (don't click it) then wait for about 1m, you'll notice that there is a scoll button. If you scroll down you will see that the auto invite is in there. That auto invite should have been floating across the screen instead it is embedded.

Comment: Can you help if I provide the code I have? It's funny because the same code works just fine on my mobile site.